# regex for lowercase letter or period followed by an uppercase letter

Tags: regex

Originally I just wanted to find a lowercase letter followed by an uppercase letter, in which case `[a-z][A-Z]` worked out pretty well.

However, in some cases the lowercase letter is replaced by a period. I'm fairly new to regex and haven't been able to find a way to implement this explicity in regex (my current solution runs through a few `if` statements and feels quite inelegant.

Is this something that can be handled well by regex?

Answer (score 6):

```
[a-z.][A-Z]
```

Read about [character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). **One** character out of those specified is matched by it.

---

Additionally:
If you were using the `.` outside a character class, you would need to escape it as it is a regex meta-character.

Comment: A period is always literal inside of a character class.

Comment: @KennethK. Corrected. My bad. The escape was unnecessary.